# Javascript replace by regex but only the first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I Want to replace spaces in a string in javascript. But only if there is a price behind it.

Example:

```
var before = 'Porto Rood / Wit 4,00';
var after = 'Porto Rood / Wit;4,00';
```

The regex I use is `\s\d+,\d{2}`

In javascript is there a way to replace only the first character of a regex match ?

Comment: Use a look-ahead, `\s(?=\d+,\d{2})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `positive lookahead` to match only the whitespace before the price.

```js
var before = 'Porto Rood / Wit 4,00',
    after = before.replace(/\s(?=\d+,\d{2})/, ';');
    console.log(after);
```

Comment: Your answer is too deep for me.  What is (?= doing in the RegEx?  When I changed that a little bit to var before = 'Porto Rood /~Wit 4.00',
    after= before.replace(/~(?=\d+\.\d{2})/, '$'); it doesn't work the same!  My '$' does not replace the '~' !!